# Papermill + Scrapbook : is it possible to reglue text in papermill notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, papermill

I use a [Papermill](https://papermill.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) notebook ("orchester_notebook") to launch multiple times a "training_notebook" with different sets of parameters.

For each set of parameters, a new "result_notebook" is saved with printed results (text) and figures.

I know how to display the figure from the "result_notebook" in my "orchester notebook"

but **I wish to also display the text results (accuracy, classification report,....) in my "orchester_notebook".**

Do you know if it is possible to reglue text via scrapbook ?

my code below :

### orchestrer_notebook

```
import papermill as pm
import scrapbook as sb

experiment_dates = [20190101, 20190102]
features = 'my_features'
model = 'my_model'
parameters = dict({'experiment_dates' : experiment_dates, 'features' : 
features, 'model' : model})

output_filename = str(experiment_dates) + '_' + features + model

pm.execute_notebook('Training.ipynb', output_filename + '.ipynb', 
parameters=parameters)

out = sb.read_notebook(output_filename + '.ipynb')
out.reglue('figure')
```

### training_notebook

```
import scrapbook as sb

# training
#...........
#............

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(data.index, data['mydata'], c='k', alpha=.5)
sb.glue('figure', fig, 'display')

print("this is my results") # how can I reglue this in orchestrer_notebook ?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I missed this in the [doc](https://github.com/nteract/scrapbook) :

```
"""glue example for recording data values"""
import scrapbook as sb

sb.glue("hello", "world") # this answers my need to reglue text
sb.glue("number", 123)
sb.glue("some_list", [1, 3, 5])
sb.glue("some_dict", {"a": 1, "b": 2})
sb.glue("non_json", df, 'arrow')
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer above doesn't work for me, I read this [other doc part](https://nteract-scrapbook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage-glue.html) and the below solution works for me :

in the training notebook :

```
sb.glue("media_as_text_only",
  media_obj,
  encoder='display',
  display=('text/plain',) # This passes [text/plain] to format_display_data's include argument
)
```

in the orchetrer notebook :

```
out.reglue("media_as_text_only")
```